# tensorflow on mac m1 - UnsatisfiableError

Tags: tensorflow, apple-m1

I am trying to install tensorflow on m1 mac. I created a new environment and then activate it. after that I entered the command below but face the problem mentioned below:

`(mlp) sina@Sinas-Mac-Mini ~ % sudo conda install -c apple tensorflow-deps`

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): | DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): repo.anaconda.com:443
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): repo.anaconda.com:443
rg:443
/ DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://repo.anaconda.com:443 "GET /pkgs/r/noarch/current_repodata.json HTTP/1.1" 304 0
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://repo.anaconda.com:443 "GET /pkgs/r/osx-arm64/current_repodata.json HTTP/1.1" 304 0

Solving environment: unsuccessful initial attempt using frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: / 
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
failed                                                                          

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

Output in format: Requested package -> Available versions

(mlp) sina@Sinas-Mac-Mini ~ %
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution on Github, though I am not sure how it resolved the problem

> sudo chmod a+w .conda